# How to download a linux image, unzip it and write it to an SD card in one line?

Tags: linux, sd-card

I am operating a Linux live image on a small USB flash drive and would like to flash an SD card with it. The image is zipped already too big for my flash drive, so I can not write it to disk. I have enough RAM to buffer the zipped and the unzipped image, so my solution was this:

```
$ sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2.5G none /mnt 
$ cd /mnt && wget http://example.com/linux.zip
$ cd /mnt && unzip linux.zip
$ sudo dd if=/mnt/linux.img of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

This feels cumbersome. How one write an image to SD card, unzipped from an archive, downloaded from the internet, without writing anything to disk in one line?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If your live image comes with `curl`, `funzip` and `dd`, something like the following should work:

```
$ curl -L http://example.com/linux.zip | funzip | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

Answer (score 10):

Try with this:
`wget http://example.com/linux.zip -q -O -| funzip | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=4M`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked fine, but I had to install `wget`, first, so I posted an answer using `curl`.

Comment: Ok, I assumed that you had `wget` because it is used in your example. Also I could edit my own answer, but it's ok.